# How do I find out how long a password is for a 7zip aes 256 encryption?

Tags: encryption, brute-force, password-cracking

I lost password to a 7zip, nothing important in it. But i'll still like to access it. I heard there is a way to find out how long the password is, but I dont know how.

Comment: So, you heard (somewhere) that it was possible and you are asking us about the details? Where did you hear this? Would the place where you heard this have details?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to determine the length of a 7-Zip password in advance of actually cracking or guessing it.

By design, most password storage schemes, when properly implemented, make it impossible to determine the length of the password unless you actually find out the entire password itself.

(In some cases, you can establish a maximum. Some password storage schemes have a known upper bound. For example, DES crypt has a maximum of 8 characters, and bcrypt has a maximum of 55 (assuming single-byte characters). But in [this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/what-would-be-the-maximum-password-length-for-a-zip-or-7z-archive-852566/), people have tried a 2000-character 7-Zip password, so it looks like that won't help you here.)